# unwanted line space between li and li

Tags: html, css

Actually I am trying to implement menu panel for application.I have a list items and i have also li items under ul under li. But I noticed that there is a line space between
li and li.Please help me in solving this.If you can see below code you will find one line space between Item3 and Sub-Items of Item3.Is There any way I can Remove the Empty Line Without Removing LI Because Firefox is not Giving the expected Result as I seen In IE8.

```
<UL>
   <LI>Item1</LI>
   <LI>Item2</LI>
   <LI>Item3</LI>
   <LI>
      <UL>
         <LI>Item3.1</LI>
         <LI>Item3.2</LI>
      </UL>
   </LI>
</UL>
```

Comment: please set up a test case on a site like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: As bPratik said,I have created jsfiddle :(http://jsfiddle.net/HSm2r/)  and Still I can see the little space between Item3 and Item3.1.Any Idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0; padding:0;` to `ul` and to `li` as well

Comment: Or only for li depends an waht you need. You can try add it to UL or change it as you want for more or less space

Answer (score 0):

Use css reset. 
You use this one http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

```
<UL>
   <LI>Item1</LI>
   <LI>Item2</LI>
   <LI>Item3</LI>
   <LI>
      <UL style="padding: 0px;">
         <LI>Item3.1</LI>
         <LI>Item3.2</LI>
      </UL>
   </LI>
</UL>
```

Try adding `padding: 0px;` to your nested `UL` element.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tanvir,I added the code as you said But Still I dont see the any change at all.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tchow002/3tshe/). Is this the result you wanted?

Comment: Yes Tanvir that is what I am expecing Sorry for my bad,it got worked but actually I have to overwrite the css styles for this and moreover that those li items under ul and li are inside the loop and I am bit confused how to overwrite css styles for only the item which are having subitems and even I see the little space between the items and any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't find any problems with your code, I've also had problems with unwanted space. It could be a problem with tabs or spaces. Try this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        ul{font-size: 0;}
        li{font-size: 12pt;}
    </style>
```